# Multiple servlets with Camel Servlet possible?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-camel

I want to expose 3 apis through my application. The pattern is as follows:

- /api/ui/* (handled by Spring) maps to servlet 1
- /api/api1/* (handled by Camel's servlet component) maps to servlet 2
- /api/api2/* (handled by Camel's servlet component) maps to servlet 3

seems I cannot do it with Camel...

This is how I register the servlet 2:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean camelServletRegistrationBean() {
    final CamelHttpTransportServlet camelServlet = new CamelHttpTransportServlet();
    final ServletRegistrationBean servletBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(camelServlet, "/api/api1/*");
    servletBean.setName("servlet2");
    return servletBean;
}

public class Api1RestInputRoute extends RouteBuilder {


   restConfiguration().component("servlet").componentProperty("servletName", "servlet2");

   rest()
      .consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
      .get("/health").to("log:api1");
}

public class Api2RestInputRoute extends RouteBuilder {


   restConfiguration().component("servlet").componentProperty("servletName", "servlet3");

   rest()
      .consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
      .get("/health").to("log:api2");
}
```

It looks like both restConfigurations set "servletName" property on the same component and the first wins.

I don't want to have /api/camel/api1/*, /api/camel/api2/* for Camel Servlet...

My Apache Camel version is 2.21.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to provide the configuration via rest dsl in Apache Camel.
Thus I spent a lot of time with debugging to find out, that there is no chance (in 2.21.5) to select the servlet to use, if you want to have multiple.

The problem is that Camel on the one hand only supports the one and only "servlet" component, so it does not help if you add "servlet1" ServletComponent, it will still use "servlet" in the end.

Although you can specify a lot of RestConfigurations, the one and only configuration for "servlet" will be selected.

And if you try to use the query part of the RestEndpoint, then the problem is that the created ServletEndpoints with properly set servletNames will anyway collide with their uri: "servlet:/health?httpMethodRestrict=GET", and thus you will have only one...

For REST I will need to switch to Spring :(

Comment: I hope @Claus Ibsen will see this and help fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will work but you might give a try to this possible workaround:
force **three distinct instances** of the servlet component, so that invoking a setter does not impact all instances.

CDI version (but principles remains for Spring)

```
public class ServletFactory {  

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("servlet1")
    public ServletComponent propertiesComponent() {     
        ServletComponent component = new ServletComponent();
        ... // Customize instance here
        return component;
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("servlet2")
    public ServletComponent propertiesComponent() {     
        ServletComponent component = new ServletComponent();
        ... // Customize instance here
        return component;
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("servlet3")
    public ServletComponent propertiesComponent() {     
        ServletComponent component = new ServletComponent();
        ... // Customize instance here
        return component;
    }
```

Of course you then have to refer to the correct names:

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet1")
```

Comment: Ah! Interesting idea! I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Sadly it does not work! The reason you cannot use multiple ServletComponents is mainly this line: url = "servlet:///%s?httpMethodRestrict=%s"; Any ServletComponent will create an Endpoint out of this line. Thus the configuration for one and only "servlet" component will apply to any created ServletEndpoint